# const { variable } = data cannot read null properties, how to safe read data?

Tags: javascript, null

instead of using `try and catch`,  there is any other solution for these **sytnx**

```
const { person, children, total } = response.data // what i looking for
```

in case the person response is null , so i got an error **cannot read properties null**.
in other case i only know using **elvis operator** *data?.data*. thats mean `response.data?.person` but i want the above code works with **null safety**, its possible ? .

**response**

```
data: {
 person: null, // these array of object
 children: {
  data: 'x',
 ... 
  ...
 },
 total: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say if my value is undefined, take in the next value and you put an empty object here

```js
const response = {}

const { person, children, total } = response.data || {}

console.log(person, children, total)
```

Comment: ah my bad i have already define `if(!!person) {  // code } ` to check , but the error is on line `const { person ..... } = response data` then i check i have wrong ID to load data and the response is null on **data** thats mean null/undefined .but thanks for ``` = response || { }```.

Comment: It’s `response.data || {}` that will replace undefined data value by {}
I don’t understand, do you still have a problem ?

Answer (score -1):

if I get your question correctly, you want to check if `response.data.person` is null or has a value. you can use several ways here. like `if-else` or `ternary` or `&&`

example:

```
const {person} = response.data;

if(person){
 // do something if person is available
} else {
 // do something if person is not available
}


// ternary operator
person ? /* do something if person is available */ : /* do something if person is not available */

// && operator (less recommended)
person && /* do something if person is available */
```